# Android Gallery Scale Center Image & Spacing Issue

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` containing a `Gallery` view.  I've defined an `onItemSelectedListener` on the `Gallery`, so that whenever an item is selected I apply a scale animation to the currently selected view.  The listener, and scaling works pretty much as expected, except for one issue.

When I defined the Gallery, I set the `spacing` attribute, however, after the view is scaled, the spacing is not being set properly.  See the image below as an example of the issue.

Any thoughts on how I can maintain the proper spacing?

[image]

Below are snippets of the code:

**main.xml**

```
<Gallery
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/featured_gallery"
    android:layout_width="1355px"
    android:layout_height="490px"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:spacing="5px"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
     />
```

**feature_selected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromXScale="1.0"
   android:toXScale="1.075"
   android:fromYScale="1.0"
   android:toYScale="1.075"
   android:duration="100"
   android:pivotX="50%"
   android:pivotY="50%"

   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
   android:fillAfter="true"> 
</scale>
```

**onItemSelectListener**

```
private class FeaturedSelectListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private Animation grow = null;
    private View lastView = null;

    public FeaturedSelectListener(Context c) {
        grow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.featured_selected);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Shrink the view that was zoomed
        try {
            if (null != lastView)
                lastView.clearAnimation();
        } catch (Exception clear) {
        }

        // Zoom the new selected view
        try {
            view.startAnimation(grow);
        } catch (Exception animate) {
        }

        // Set the last view so we can clear the animation
        lastView = view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried to set both left and right margin on selected image? maybe it can help you.

Comment: I just tried, and unfortunately, that did not work.  If I remove pivotX from the animation, then there is spacing on the left hand side of the scaled view, but not the right. The items on the right are not being moved over properly.

Comment: Hello Steve, i need to do same animation in Gallery, if you have achieve this, can you send me code please?

Answer (score 1):

View animation in Android is a major PITA. It almost never work correctly when the view has to "move other view". Sometimes using the fill_after parameters, the view will not respond anymore on touch event. God knows why.

I would give you two suboptimal options :

1. Instead of making the front view bigger, make the side view smaller. The interspace will grow which might be more appealing than what you have now
2. Remove the fill_after, then use an AnimationListener and set the view size using LayouParameters in the animationEnd.

Good luck.

Comment: Haha...thanks for telling me something I already know...the PITA part that is.  I'll try those suggestions out. Thanks.